# Windows KMFD HelloWorld Driver Deployment Task Failed

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2015, kernel

I need to write a Kernel Driver for Windows. Since this is my first time attempting something like this, I started with Windows' HelloWorld example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665(v=vs.85).aspx

I encounter my problem when installing the driver to the target machine. The console on the target machine gives the following output:

> Test Authoring and Execution Framework v5.3 for x64
>
> **StartGroup: DriverTestsTasks:: _DriverRemoval**
>  Driver
>   Certificate File: KmfdHelloWorld.cer
>  Driver Inf
>   File:KmfdHelloWorld.inf
>  Driver Hardware ID:
>   Root\KmdfHelloWorld
>  Driver package GUID: x64
>  Import Driver To
>   Store: 1
>  Uninstall Driver: 1
>  Debug Deployment: 1
>  COM
>   failure occurred. HRESULT: 0x80040154
>  **Class not registered**
>
> Class not registered
>
> Failed: A failure occured while removing the previous driver
>   installation
>  EndGroup: DriverTestTasks:: _DriverRemoval [Failed]
>
> Non-passing Tests:
>  DriverTestTasks::_DriverRemoval [Failed]
>   SummaryL Total=1, Passed=0, Failed=1, Blocked=0, Not Run=0, Skipped=0

As explained in the tutorial, I am using Visual Studio 2015. My test machine is running Windows 10 in a VM. All the other tests pass. The driver is copied to the target machine and gets installed, but fails this one procedure and hence I can't use the Debugger explained at the end of the tutorial.

Comment: Hey, has a solution been found for this issue? I have a friend experiencing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the step of remove the previous installation by remove checkbox at "project setting"-> Driver install-> Deployment