# WDK "A failure occurred while removing previous driver installations"

Tags: wdk

I've followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1 to setup my local machine with Visual Studio and a VM on my local network as the target machine for debugging a kernel mode driver I am trying to create.

Setup of WDK and the provisioning works fine, building the driver works fine, but when I F5 to cause a deploy of the driver to the target machine and debug it, I will see a few console windows pop up on the target, usually ending in red, but the host instance says all is fine per the output from the Driver Output page, telling me:

```
[15:30:07:093]: Removing any existing files from test execution folder.
[15:30:07:112]: Copying required files for "Gathering kernel debugger settings".
[15:30:08:112]: [Gathering kernel debugger settings] Command Line:
$KitRoot$\Testing\Runtimes\TAEF\te.exe "%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestTasks.dll" /select:"@Name='DriverTestTasks::_LogDebuggerSettings'" /rebootStateFile:%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\DriverTestReboot.xml /enableWttLogging /wttDeviceString:$LogFile:file="%SystemDrive%\DriverTest\Run\Gathering_kernel_debugger_settings_00038.wtl",writemode=append,encoding=unicode,nofscache=true,EnableLvl="WexStartTest|WexEndTest|WexXml|WexProperty|WexCreateContext|WexCloseContext|*" /runas:Elevated
[15:30:11:418]: Result Summary: Total=1, Passed=1, Failed=0, Blocked=0, Warned=0, Skipped=0
[15:30:11:419]: Task "Gathering kernel debugger settings" completed successfully
```

Viewing Driver Test Group Explorer though tells a different story, that the Driver Preparation failed. Drilling into the log the cert install works, the exit code comes back as expected, then I see the following:

```
Process completed successfully Message 12-27-2023 03:30:26.108 PM 
The system cannot find the file specified.  Message 12-27-2023 03:30:26.114 PM 
A failure occurred while removing previous driver installations
File: , Line: -1

Error Type: 

Error Code: 0x0

Error Text: Error 0x00000000 
Error 12-27-2023 03:30:26.118 PM 
DriverTestTasks::_DriverPreparation
Result: Fail
```

I can manually copy the driver files across, however I'm trying to speed things up with what *should* work from Visual Studio and the WDK, but for the life of me cannot figure out how/where else to look to troubleshoot this.

I've stood up extra VMs, same result. Had one VM try to deploy to another, same result.

In some reading, I encountered this SO question [Windows KMFD HelloWorld Driver Deployment Task Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162661/windows-kmfd-helloworld-driver-deployment-task-failed) and the answer is one I've tried, going into Project Properties -> Driver Install -> Deployment & unchecking the "Remove previous driver versions before deployment". Same result, the Driver preparation step fails with the same message.

What am I missing/not seeing?